# Android 8 notifications setSound not working

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I have the following code but everytime I just hear the default android sound.

```
        // create  channel
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(ANDROID_CHANNEL_ID,
                ANDROID_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        // Sets whether notifications posted to this channel should display notification lights
        channel.enableLights(true);
        // Sets whether notification posted to this channel should vibrate.
        channel.enableVibration(true);
        // Sets the notification light color for notifications posted to this channel
        channel.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);
        // Sets whether notifications posted to this channel appear on the lockscreen or not
        //channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
        channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+this.getPackageName()+"/" + R.raw.aperturaabductores);

        AudioAttributes att = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
                .build();
        channel.setSound(uri,att);
```

This is my sound [pablomonteserin.es/aperturaabductores.wav](http://pablomonteserin.es/aperturaabductores.wav)

Comment: Tested. working in emulator.

Comment: Is not working in my emulator and device neither. Did you test on Android 8?. Please note that i want to load a custom sound.

Comment: i did with mine custom sound, i know its 8. Provide the sound, i will try with that.

Comment: This is my sound http://pablomonteserin.es/aperturaabductores.wav

Comment: The difference for me was setting the sound file on the channel for android oreo as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried to see the difference between your sound file and mine. I used Audacity software.
Your sound file has sampling rate 22050Hz while the sound files i use are sampled at 44100Hz. So i converted your sound file sampling rate to 44100Hz and used that as notification sound. Now it works.

The problem is with the sound file. May be it's new change in Android O because it's working fine on older Android version.

This is how to resample-[image]

Comment: can you post your code, because I am still having the problem in 8.1.0

Comment: I tried all the possible solutions, after hours of trying this saved me! you save my life!! :) 
remember to uninstall the app when you try, otherwise the notification channel will not update...thanks dude!

Comment: could you please provide  your audio file

Answer (score 5):

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            Notification.Builder notificationBuilder =
                    new Notification.Builder(MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext(), NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .setContentTitle(pTitle)
                            .setContentText(messageBody)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            //.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX) // this is deprecated in API 26 but you can still use for below 26. check below update for 26 API
                            //.setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            // Configure the notification channel.
            AudioAttributes att = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
                    .build();
            notificationChannel.setSound(defaultSoundUri,att);
            notificationChannel.setDescription(messageBody);
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
            if (imageThumbnail != null) {
                notificationBuilder.setStyle(new Notification.BigPictureStyle()
                        .bigPicture(imageThumbnail).setSummaryText(messageBody));
            }
            notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());

        } else {
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext())
                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .setContentTitle(pTitle)
                            .setContentText(messageBody)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX) // this is deprecated in API 26 but you can still use for below 26. check below update for 26 API
                            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            if (imageThumbnail != null) {
                notificationBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                        .bigPicture(imageThumbnail).setSummaryText(messageBody));
            }
            notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());

        }
```

Comment: what is defaultSoundUri?]

Comment: Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);