# Android Oreo Does not Play Custom Sound for Notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

I am trying to add a custom sound to notification for API > 26. Below is the code

```
NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("channel id","channel name",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                    .build();
notificationChannel.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "/raw/beep"),audioAttributes);
```

The problem here is that it, plays default piano sound of device rather than playing beep sound from assets. I am not allowed to use ringtone manager but common sense stats that notification sound should be that which is specified rather than default.

It works fine for API <= 26

Comment: Does it work for API below 26?

Comment: Look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019496/notification-sound-on-api-26

Comment: Dear Pankaj, its using ringtone manager which I dont wanna use because of requirements.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46268684/android-8-notifications-setsound-not-working)

Comment: No that didnt help as well. My OS version is 8.1.0

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally I managed to find a solution on my own. Below is the code

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            if(notificationSoundUri != null){
                // Changing Default mode of notification
                notificationCompatBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

                // Creating an Audio Attribute
                AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                        .build();

                // Creating Channel
                NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(context.getString(R.string.channel_id_prayers),context.getString(R.string.channel_name_prayers),NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
                notificationChannel.setSound(notificationSoundUri,audioAttributes);
                mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
            }
}
mNotificationManager.notify(0, notificationCompatBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Yes, but once the channel is created the only way to change its sound or vibration is through the android settings

Comment: That is up to user who wants to change or mute sound but pro-grammatically I was require to set custom sound

Comment: Thank you! Setting the sound on the notification channel worked for me as well in Oreo. I'm getting my sounds from android resources.

Comment: OK, it means that you have to `createNotificationChannel` with  `audioAttributes` then it would work.

Comment: where have u defined notificationSoundUri

Comment: Is there any way to Inside app user can change the sound setting (disable or enable) considering notification channel functionality?

Comment: If you need to make changes to sound, simply delete the channel and recreate it

Comment: @LionHeart In my android Pie(9) doesn't work. If you know why then can you please suggest  me any solution.

Comment: @Ali - were you able to find a solution for Android Pie(9). This code works for me on Android 8 only